# Is Running Tor software legal in Europe?

Tags: criminal-law, internet, privacy, european-union

What is the legality of doing the following, under European and, in particular, Spanish law?

- Using the Tor browser
- Setting up a Tor relay
- Setting up a Tor exit node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer but I'm familiar with the law and using Tor.

Using the Tor browser and Setting up a Tor relay is perfectly fine but its what you do with it that can make it illegal.

Setting up a Tor exit node is fine unless you mean your monitoring the exit node to steal info from other Tor users